# Saving file using the QFileDialog::getSaveFileName to restricted location doesn't give error message

Tags: macos, qt, qfiledialog

i Am working on sample QT project on MAC and to save files i am using the  QFileDialog::getSaveFileName API with native dialog and if i save the file to directory which is read only it still gets saved !!! but the behaviour should be it should give error message. When i observed on windows system everything works fine it gives error message but on MAC id doesn't can anyone faced this earlier??

Comment: Are you sure that the directory is read only for your user? I would be very surprised if OSX would allow creating a file in a read only directory. At the end, this is not something which is handled by Qt, but by the os...

Comment: i was just curious so just created the directory with read only permission for all then tried to save the file and it get saved !!!..but by using cocoa native dialogue it doesn't allow but however by using the Qt API it does

Comment: Did you actually create a file, or you just obtained a file name from QFileDialog::getSaveFileName() ? In documentation there is no mention of file permissions, so they might as well be just ignored, and the application must signal such errors to user.

Comment: Can you show us the code which you are running on Windows and OSX and which demonstrates the behaviour you observed? Can you confirm that you have tried the identical code on Windows and OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getSaveFileName()` just returns a path to the location the user chose. It doesn't actually create any files. Permission are not an issue until you attempt to actually create/write to the file.

Comment: The strange thing is that sandy writes that he observes different behaviour between OSX and Windows, so I suspected that he actually really created a file ...

Comment: yes i actually created file manually with read only permission and then i used getSaveFileName() to just store the some x file to that location and here is my code  
                                                                                                                 QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(NULL,"EXport Dir", lastExportDir, filters.join(";;"),NULL,QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly); 

...where  i am using some filters and then the lastExportDir points to the last exported directory as the name suggests.

Comment: Yes but from what you're saying it sounds like you're expecting `getSaveFileName()` to respect permissions, which it never will because it doesn't actually do anything that requires permissions.

Comment: Yeah thats right but i was confused with the fact that it works fine on windows but not on Mac   anyways i solved the problem by checking manually the permission for selected folder and its working!!.